# Pyspark: Convert Column from String Type to Timestamp Type

Tags: casting, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I have been using pyspark 2.3. I have data frame containing 'TIME' column in String format for DateTime values. where the column looks like:

```
+---------------+
|           TIME|
+---------------+
| 2016/04/14 190|
| 2016/04/15 180|
|2016/04/14 1530|
|2016/04/16 1530|
| 2016/04/17 160|
+---------------+
```

where the first two digits in  `190` or `1530`  representing the hour and the rest is the minutes.
I tried to convert it to a timestamp type using the following lines:

```
df.withColumn('TIME_timestamp',fn.unix_timestamp('TIME','yyyy/MM/dd HHMM').cast(TimestampType()))
```

and also :

```
df.withColumn('TIME_timestamp', fn.to_timestamp("TIME", 'yyyy/MM/dd HHMM'))
```

but the resulting is:

```
+---------------+-------------------+
|           TIME|     TIME_timestamp|
+---------------+-------------------+
| 2016/04/14 190|               null|
| 2016/04/15 180|               null|
|2016/04/14 1530|               null|
|2016/04/16 1530|               null|
| 2016/04/17 160|               null|
+---------------+-------------------+
```

So the desired Dataframe should look like:

```
+---------------+
| TIME_timestamp|
+---------------+
| 16-04-15 19:00|
| 16-04-15 18:00|
| 16-04-15 15:30|
| 16-04-15 15:30|
| 16-04-15 16:00|
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use capital `M` to identify the months as well as the minutes; the minutes should be identified with `m`, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html). A working example using `to_timestamp` is given below, hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('2016/04/14 190',),
     ('2016/04/15 180',),
     ('2016/04/14 1530',),
     ('2016/04/16 1530',),
     ('2016/04/17 160',)
    ],
    ("TIME",)
)

df.withColumn('TIME_timestamp',F.to_timestamp("TIME", "yyyy/MM/dd HHmm")).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+-------------------+
|           TIME|     TIME_timestamp|
+---------------+-------------------+
| 2016/04/14 190|2016-04-14 19:00:00|
| 2016/04/15 180|2016-04-15 18:00:00|
|2016/04/14 1530|2016-04-14 15:30:00|
|2016/04/16 1530|2016-04-16 15:30:00|
| 2016/04/17 160|2016-04-17 16:00:00|
+---------------+-------------------+
```